# What are the FAA regs regarding landing a helicopter off airport?

Tags: faa-regulations, helicopter

I have been mulling over getting a [Mosquito helicopter](http://www.innovatortech.ca), the experimental version with the uprated gas or turbine engine and larger fuel capacity. It's unwise to try to fly any of the Mosquitos without at least a rotary wing solo ticket, and if you have that, you may as well get the better version so you can log the time, and take advantage of the greater range and power. This leads to an interesting question:

What are the regulations regarding where a helicopter can be landed? Obviously, it can be landed in a lot of places, but what does officialdom have to say about where a helicopter can and cannot be landed?

Comment: Interesting question indeed. It could be extended to non-commercial aircraft as well, is it possible to land some kind of aircraft in your property, for those who have a big property.

Comment: oops, didn't see that one.

Comment: I am inclined to leave this open as *not* a duplicate because: `A` this question also appears to incorporate the ultralight question, and `B` the related question does not ask about FAA regulations as specifically, nor are any pertinent FAA regulations cited in the answers. In those answers, the only correct information offered is along the lines of "*See state or local regulations*".

Answer (score 1):

There are no Federal Laws prohibiting landing rotor craft off field.

14 CFR 91.119

> (1) A helicopter may be operated at less than the minimums prescribed in paragraph (b) or (c) of this section, provided each person operating the helicopter complies with any routes or altitudes specifically prescribed for helicopters by the FAA;

Part B and C, for reference

> Except when necessary for takeoff or landing, no person may operate an aircraft below the following altitudes:
>
> (b) Over congested areas. Over any congested area of a city, town, or settlement, or over any open air assembly of persons, an altitude of 1,000 feet above the highest obstacle within a horizontal radius of 2,000 feet of the aircraft.
>
> (c) Over other than congested areas. An altitude of 500 feet above the surface, except over open water or sparsely populated areas. In those cases, the aircraft may not be operated closer than 500 feet to any person, vessel, vehicle, or structure.

However, state laws, local laws, zoning laws, etc. change from location to location. You need to make sure you plan where you are landing beforehand and check these laws.

For example, in the State of New Jersey, helicopters can only be landed at the following locations:

1. Permanent public use heliport or vertiport
2. Permanent special use or restricted use helistop or vertiport
3. Temporary helistop or vertiport

([Reference](http://www.state.nj.us/transportation/airwater/aviation/faqs.shtm))